# Previous Next Shortcode for custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode

I'm trying to create a shortcode for a custom post type (project) in wordpress, which should be used inside the content/tinymce field. Right now the prev/next link output only shows up on top of the content. I've already changed echo to return, but this did not solve the issue. What am I doing wrong? Thanks :)

```
function custom_prev_next_post_nav($atts, $content = null) { 
if ( ! is_singular( 'project' ) )  return;
$pnstring = '<div id="prev-next">'; 
$pnstring .= previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous' );
$pnstring .= next_post_link( '%link', 'Next' );
$pnstring .= '</div>';
return $pnstring; 
}
add_shortcode( 'prevnext', 'custom_prev_next_post_nav' );
```

Comment: If the shortcode is below the content in the editor, it might be a css issue. Inspect the #prev-next div.